# Yolo Darknet Detecting Only Specific Class like Person, Cat, Dog etc

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, darknet

We are using YOLO Darknet for object detection. We are using Python3, tensorflow 1.0, numpy, opencv 3. Using yolo.weight for detection.  As per given in below link :
 https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow#cameravideo-file-demo

When we run it on a video, it is simultaneously detecting all the objects, which are not required?

Please guide us on how we can only detect specific class name to be searched.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just follow the steps that @JP Kim has mentioned - you will get a video out with just your labels, however it would also output other objects as one of your labels.

[There's a specific section of the darkflow repo](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow#training-on-your-own-dataset) which exactly tells what to do if you wish to have a different output. TLDR - you should retrain your model. They show this by taking up an example of 3 classes.

But, let me walk you through the process anyway. Let's consider that you have a video and you just need to track all people in it. So, we only need to track 1 type of object - 'person'.

1. We make a copy of `tiny-yolo-voc.cfg` file in `cfg` directory. Let's follow their convention and name this `tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg` where suffix `1c` represents the number of classes. The reason for choosing `tiny-yolo-voc` and not some other config as our base model is it's a smaller network which is trainable on smaller GPUs. From what I've observed other configs require 10GB+ Graphic memory and they used to make my machine go out of memory.
2. We'll make required changes in `tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg` file :

   - edit `classes` variable to `classes=1`
   - In the last `convolutional` section just before `region`, we will change `filter` variable to `5 * (num_class + 5) = 5 * (1+5) = 30`. So, set `filters=30`
3. We'll edit the `labels.txt` file in the darkflow source directory and have only 1 line inside it which says `person`, since we need only 1 type of label.
4. Now, we need to train our model. However, for training, we first require dataset to be there.

   - Now, if your label is one of the existing label of VOC datset or CoCo dataset, then you could just download one of VOC / Coco datsets. In our case `person` is the type of object we need to track, and that is already a type of object in VOC dataset. So, we'll use VOC dataset.
   - However, if you wish to use YOLO to classify and track a new type of object, then you need to prepare your own dataset and annotations. For this custom object purpose, you could follow the part 5-8 of [this youtube video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg4T9iJkwhE). These videos showcase an example of how to use YOLO to track and classify `fidget_spinner`.
5. Download VOC Dataset because it contains enough data and annotations for our type of object `person`

   ```
   # Download the Pascal VOC dataset:
   curl -O https://pjreddie.com/media/files/VOCtest_06-Nov-2007.tar
   tar xf VOCtest_06-Nov-2007.tar
   ```
6. We're not going to train from scratch. So, we're actually going to load weights for `tiny-yolo-voc` model and start re-training from there, for our specific use-case (just `person` class). For this, we musthave  weights downloaded for `tiny-yolo-voc`. You can find the weights [here for YOLO v2](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolov2/). We will download the weights for [Tiny YOLO for VOC dataset](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov2-tiny-voc.weights). Move the file to `/darkflow/bin/` directory after downloading.
7. Once we've downloaded this, it's necessary to have the base model config file and the weight file having same name. Since renaming config is not a good idea, we will rename the weights we've downloaded from `yolov2-tiny-voc.weights` to `tiny-yolo-voc.weights`. This is required because when we train, we provided weights file and darkflow tries to pick up the corresponding config file as a reference for training the new model.

This is also mentioned on the darkflow repo page :

> When darkflow sees you are loading tiny-yolo-voc.weights it will look for tiny-yolo-voc.cfg in your cfg/ folder and compare that configuration file to the new one you have set with --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg. In this case, every layer will have the same exact number of weights except for the last two, so it will load the weights into all layers up to the last two because they now contain different number of weights.

7. Now, we can train our model. You can remove the `--gpu 0.9` part if you do not have a GPU to train this.

   ```
   # Train the net on the Pascal dataset:
   flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights --train --dataset "~/VOCdevkit/VOC2007/JPEGImages" --annotation "~/VOCdevkit/VOC2007/Annotations" --gpu 0.9
   ```
8. Hit Ctrl+C to end training when you think the loss is not reducing anymore. Usually a good loss / ave loss is 1 or below 1.

You would have noted that after every 250 steps, darkflow will keep saving checkpoints in the `ckpt/` directory. Once you stop training, you can use any of these checkpoints to test out your model.

9. We will run it on a video of people and let it save a new video with bounding box predictions. Let's use 1500th step checkpoint for this example.

   ```
   flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg --load 1500 --demo video-input.mp4 --gpu 0.9 --saveVideo
   ```

When you run this, it would show the FPS at which the model is able to work with your video. This could vary depending upon your machine. Depending upon the FPS and the length of the video, it could take some time for this to finish. Once the process is finished, you'll have a `video.avi` created in `darkflow/` directory.

This should only have `person` type of objects detected in the video.

If the output isn't great, you can train your model further, and/or vary thresholds, or other parameters to get better outputs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should set `filters=18` for single class detection. The formula I've seen is `filters= num/3*(classes+1+4)` with num=3 for small, medium and large objects. https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/582

Answer (score 4):

From what I've found, you can do that as follows:

1. copy your original yolo cfg file to the new file and edit value for
   classes in [region] section to the number of classes you want to
   detect.
2. create label text file and put the class name you want to detect
   (subset of original classes)

then,

```
flow --model cfg/your_new_copied_file.cfg --load path/to/weight_file --demo your_video.mp4 --labels your_labels.txt --saveVideo
```

That's it.

But the problem is, overall detection accuracy goes down significantly. Often it detects totally different objects as the objects in labels. 
(maybe darkflow just pick the top confident guess among the labels if it's above threshold?)

So, If you want to detect just some of objects among other classes while skipping other objects (i.e. recognize them but skipping), I think it's better to edit darkflow sources to accept additional parameter (like --mark marklabels.txt).

Comment: This answer is very wrong.  You cannot edit the configuration and names file and expect the weights to magically know that things have changed.  This exact type of answer was also discussed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70106904/13022

Answer (score 0):

If you would like some fast results without retraining the `darknet`, the official suggestion can be found at https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/2920#issuecomment-482810023 as answered by AlexeyAB, which I recap as follows:

> Just add `dont_show` before each line except cat, dog, person here: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/data/coco.names
>
> and run (something like the following command):
>
> ```
> ./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights -thresh 0.25
> ```

So for each class that you would like to have no output of, such as person, do in the "coco.names" file in the first line:

```
dont_show person
```

The others are similar if you would not want to show as well.

Comment: @Stéphane I have not implied it would alter the length of time to run the neural network. I meant this would be the easiest way by saying "fast results". I think you are being too literal.